# Activity indicator starts before function is called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a button that calls this IBAction function. The activity indicator starts as soon as the app runs instead of when the button is tapped, disappears as expected when the function completes its work then never appears again. This seems like a really simple interface thing but I'm stumped. Any ideas?

```
 @IBAction func saveToCamera() {

    // Start the spinner
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvas.frame.size)
    canvas.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)



}

func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
     activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        if error != nil {
             println(error) }
    }
```

Comment: What properties have you set on the the activity indicator in the storyboard scene?

Comment: You have a bigger problem - your problem is understanding synchronous versus asynchronous programming. You have put all your code in one function and the last line is stopAnimating() that means the animator will never ever show after you have called this function because you are starting it but then a microsecond later you are stopping it so it will never appear to the user. Duncan has shown how to make it stop. Make sure you understand why what you have done cannot work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have the `isAnimating` property on the activity view set to true in your storyboard. make sure it's false, and that the `hidesWhenStopped` property is true.

Then your code won't work as posted. If you want the spinner to stop animating when the call to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` is complete, you need to provide a `completionTarget` and `completionSelector`. Something like this:

(Edited to use correct method signature for completion method)

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(
  image, 
  self, 
  "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", 
  nil)
```

And a method to be called once the write is complete:

```
func image(image: UIImage, 
  didFinishSavingWithError 
  error: NSErrorPointer, 
  contextInfo: UnsafePointer<Void>) 
  {
     activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
     if error != nil 
     {
       println(error) 
     }
  }
```

Comment: It solved the problem as asked although the app now crashes when the button is tapped. Gruntcakes has a point. I see that I'm starting it and stopping it in the function. I set it to Animating in IB thinking that meant 'not static image'. Didn't realise it was the default state I was setting. Unchecked that. I made the edit above based on @Duncan-C's suggestion.

Comment: The error was 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: index (3) out of bounds [-1, 2]'. I was able to fix it with the above code from the article "Accessing the iOS 8 Camera and Photo Library in Swift - Techotopia"

Comment: Gotcha. I did't look that closely at the completion method for UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum. It seems it has a more complex signature. I'll edit my answer.